# Pickle give Ran out of input while the file is not empty

Tags: python, list, file, pickle

Maybe this question has been asked many times in stack**overflow** . But i can't find a solution for my code .

So , it's a very simple **Def** that get the data from a file called **eleve.dat** , then put it into a list in way to use the data from the **classes** inside that file .

so here is my code :

```
def show() :
E = []
file = open("d:\BullApp\eleve.dat", 'rb')
ch =""

while True :
    e = load(file)
    E.append(e)
```

While **running it using a Qt5 button** (it's an application for school project ) it gives me this **error** :

[image]

And i want to mention that the Binary file **eleve.dat** *isn't empty* and the other function of filling the file works perfectly .

So , i hope i find solution about this , and **please don't put my Question as Duplicate** because i didn't found the anwser yet .

And thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code it seems you have an infinite loop. Right now I can think of only 2 options best for you.
1 - Check whether you are really getting values by printing them

```
...
while True :
    e = load(file)
    print(e)
    E.append(e)
```

If yes then you can terminate at the end of file like this

```
...
while True :
    try:
        e = load(file)
        print(e)
        E.append(e)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

2 - Which is my personal favorite to save and load data, my `save_and_load.py` script.

```
import pickle
def save(data, file_name):
    with open(file_name + '.dat', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(data))

def load(file_name):
    with open(file_name + '.dat', 'rb') as f:
        return(pickle.loads(f.read()))
```

You can read about pickle [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-pickling). Short and simple :)